# Weird errors in Xcode in the code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have a problem figuring out exactly whats wrong here:

```
-(void) fireShots {
    [laserBeam stop];
    [laserBeam setCurrentTime:0];
    [laserBeam play];
    UIImageView *aShot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(actorImage.center.x, actorImage.center.y, 26, 36)];
    [aShot setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Laser- rød.png"]];
    [allShots addObject:aShot];

    if (moveAllShots == nil)
        moveAllShots = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/50
                                                        target:self
                                                      selector:@selector(moveAllShots)
                                                      userInfo:nil
                                                       repeats:YES];
    [actorImage.superview addSubview:aShot];
}
```

The method have 3 errors: Expected ; after expression (tries to fix it by inserting it at the moveallShots == nil, which is obviously incorrect.
Expected Expression (same line, it is the line that says [allShots addObject:aShot];
use of undeclared identifier aShot, that can't be true either as it is made in that method.

Really can't figure this one out. Thanks on advance,

/JBJ

Comment: NOTE - i just fixed the issue with the NSTimer moveAllShots, but the ones on the line with [allShots addObject:aShot]; still persists - i am sure the NSMutableArray is allocated, so i have no idea whats wrong here.

Comment: NSMutableArray *allShots; in the .h file of that class

Comment: either you forgot semicolon or }. check your code properly.

Comment: you also have a memory leak for 'aShot'

Comment: A memory leak? where? aShot is added to the array of allShots, so that it can later be removed? how is that a leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample method `fireShots` it looks like you have never defined `laserBeam`, `allShots`, and `moveAllShots`.  Your errors will be solved by defining the variables in the local scope.  Looking at how you are trying to use the variables you may be better off defining a custom class and adding the variables as properties using accessors to get and set the values.

For example: since `allShots` is defined in your header file, use a property to access that instance variable.

For use on using properties, see: [The Objective-C Programming Language: Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

A google search will also turn up with some concise tutorials.